# Kinect as Motion Sensor

Tags: computer-vision, kinect, motion-detection

I'm planning on creating an app that does something like this: http://www.zonetrigger.com/articles/Kinect-software/

That means, I want to be able to set up "Trigger Zones" using the Kinect and it's 3d Image. Now I know that Microsoft is stating that the Kinect can detect the skeleton of up to 6 People. 
For me however, it would be enough to detect whether something is entering a trigger zone and where.

Does anyone know if the Kinect can be programmed to function as a simple Motion Sensor, so it can detect more than 6 entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well known that Kinect cannot detect more than 5 entries (just kidding). All you need to do is to get a depth map (z-map) from Kinect, and then convert it into a 3d map using these formulas,

```
X = (((cols - cap_width) * Z ) / focal_length_X);
Y = (((row - cap_height)* Z ) / focal_length_Y);
Z = Z;
```

Where row and col are calculated from the image center (not upper left corner!) and focal is a focal length of Kinect in pixels (~570). Now you can specify the exact locations in 3D where if the pixels appear, you can do whatever you want to do. Here are more pointers:

1. You can use openCV for the ease of visualization. To read a frame from Kinect after it was initialized you just need something like this:

   Mat inputMat = Mat(h, w, CV_16U, (void*) depth_gen.GetData());
2. You can easily visualize depth maps using [histogram equalization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20262215/457687) (it will optimally spread 10000 Kinect levels among your available 255 levels of grey)
3. It is sometimes desirable to do object segmentation grouping spatially close pixels with similar depth together. I did this several years ago, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20229436/457687) but had to delete the floor and/or common surface on which object stayed otherwise all the object were connected and extracted as a single large segment.